# Find the index value of an array based on an array item object property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this array here (***stressValues***):

```
[ { angeredoutsidecontrol: 1 }, { difficultiespileup: 2 } ]
```

I'd like to find the array index value based on the property name of one of the contained objects, such as **angeredoutsidecontrol**, which would return **0**

How can I achieve this?

This is what I have so far:

```
for(const value of values) {
  const stressValue = Object.values(value)[0];
  const valueName = Object.keys(value)[0];

  for (const name in stressValues) {
    if (name === valueName) {
      console.log(name);
      console.log(values.indexOf(name)); // trying to get it to return 0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you have done to achieve your goal?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Also, what if the array contains multiple object with the same property name. Do you return all indices or just one?

Comment: `arr.map((e, i) => {e.index = i; return e})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const arr = [ { angeredoutsidecontrol: 1 }, { difficultiespileup: 2 } ];


function checkForKey(arr, key) {
    // loop through array
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        const value = arr[i];
        // if value has the key, return the index
        if (value.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}


console.log('angeredoutsidecontrol', checkForKey(arr, 'angeredoutsidecontrol'));
console.log('difficultiespileup', checkForKey(arr, 'difficultiespileup'));
```

Comment: Perfect, I was quite damn close too. Thanks a lot, I'll accept this as the answer when I'm able to.

Answer (score 2):

If the objects have always only one property, you can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) with [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```js
var stressValues = [ { angeredoutsidecontrol: 1 }, { difficultiespileup: 2 } ];

var angerIndex = stressValues.findIndex((value) => Object.keys(value)[0] === 'angeredoutsidecontrol');
console.log(angerIndex);
```

**EDIT:** If you want a more generic solution, you can use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), so we check if the object includes, in its keys, the specified one:

```js
var stressValues = [ { angeredoutsidecontrol: 1, sadness: 3 }, { difficultiespileup: 2 } ];

var angerIndex = stressValues.findIndex((value) => Object.keys(value).includes('angeredoutsidecontrol'));
console.log(angerIndex);
```

Comment: This _assumes_ only one key/value pair per object.

Comment: Yes, it works only in this case

Comment: I can use Neal's solution programatically to achieve what I'm going for but thanks for your answer.

Comment: @AnthonyMayfield I edited my answer with a more generic solution. Might be useful for you